# In the image shown, are electrons more likely to flow from cathode to anode through the green or the purple wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electrons

[image: Beam deflection with wires]

Lets say an electron beam is confined to two identical wires (green and purple) while remaining in the magnetic field shown. If the electrons are moving at speeds equal to that of the original beam, will the current be higher in the lower (purple) wire?

Comment: Well, it isn't a beam if it is in the wires, and those wires are going to short out the power supply. As for the magnetic field effects on electrons in solids (like wires), look up the Hall effect.

Comment: This question is unclear. What do you mean by electron beams confined to wires? Usually you need vacuum for electron beams.

Comment: @freecharly: I just meant that the electricity would flow into the the wires. I'm assuming the wires also have no resistance and therefore the speed (and therefore magnetic field strength) of the moving electrons is maintained. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that electrons will not have any preference going througth any of the wires. Key point here is the green-purple contact with the cathode, and taking the dimensions of cables you system electric field his not big enougth for making Hall effect to matter, as the electric field that tells electrons which way to go is stronger and they have no energetic reason to go trougth the purple wire instead of the green one.

On the other hand, if you had bigger contact, lets say a metal plate that fills the first half of the tube, and put the purple cable where in your picture the electron hits the tube, then most of the electrons will go througth this cable.

But this is more because of geometric reasons. In you picture probably electrons will not choose any of the cables because of the magnetic field.